# Selecting a sublist from a list of lists

Tags: r, list, sorting, subset

I want to remove a sublist from a list of lists. For example, say I have a big list structured like this

```
mybiglist <- vector('list', 5)
names(mybiglist) <- paste0('item:', seq_along(mybiglist))
for(i in seq_along(mybiglist)){
  a <- rbinom(8, 5, i/10)
  b <- sum(c)

  tmp <- list(binomial = a, total = b)
  mybiglist[[i]] <- tmp
}
```

and I want to find the sublist (the entire item:x) with the highest total and save that list as a new object.

What is an efficient way to achieve this? I prefer not to convert to a different object type, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
mybiglist[[which.max(sapply(mybiglist, `[[`, 'total'))]]
```

gives:

> ```
> $binomial
> [1] 4 2 2 5 5 1 3 2
>
> $total
> [1] 24
> ```

Assigning that to a new object will give you a new list as well:

> ```
> > new <- mybiglist[[which.max(sapply(mybiglist, `[[`, 'total'))]]
> > class(new)
> [1] "list"
> ```